# Cancellable Encryption method for Windows Store App?

Tags: c#, security, encryption, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

Is there any way to encrypt/decrypt using UWP with the ability to cancel the operation in the middle? All I found were the [methods of CryptographicEngine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.cryptographicengine.aspx)    and though there exists a `DecryptAsync`, there's no Async Encrypt. What's more - even `DecryptAsync` doesn't have a way to be cancelled.

If there's some way at least for desktops, if not mobile - I'd like to know about that.

Comment: Just curious - why would you need this?